# Not declared in this scope(error in C language)

Tags: c, function, struct

I have these pieces of code:
Header:

```
#ifndef hotel
#define hotel
typedef struct hotel
{
       char name_of_H[50];
       char adress[50];
       int nr_rooms;
       int floors;
       float stars;
}HOTEL;
void inputh(HOTEL *h, int n);
void outputh(HOTEL *h, int n);
int searchh( HOTEL *h, int n, char *key);
void swaph( HOTEL *h, int k1, int k2);
void sorth( HOTEL *h, int n);
void modifyh(HOTEL *h, int k);
int writeh(HOTEL *h, int n, char * fname);
HOTEL* appendh(HOTEL *h, int *n,HOTEL newh);
HOTEL* inserth(HOTEL *h, int *n, int k,HOTEL newh);
HOTEL* delh(HOTEL *h  , int *n, int k);
#endif
```

Prototype of functions(just 2 of them):

```
   HOTEL* appendh(HOTEL *h, int *n, HOTEL newh)
     {  int i;
HOTEL *p;
p=(HOTEL *)realloc(h,(*n+1)*sizeof(*p));
if (p==NULL) {return p;}
p[*n]= newh;
*n=*n+1;
return p;
}
HOTEL* inserth(HOTEL *h, int *n, int k,HOTEL newh)
{  int i;
HOTEL *p;
p=(HOTEL*)realloc(h,(*n+1)*sizeof(*p));
if (p==NULL) {return p;}
for(i=*n; i>k; i--)
{ p[i]= p[i-1]; }
 p[k]= newh;
*n=(*n)+1;
return p;
}
```

And in main:

```
printf("Enter information about hotel:");
    printf("Name of hotel: "); fflush(stdin);
    gets(newh.name_of_H);//here is the error
    printf("Adress of hotel:     "); fflush(stdin);
    gets(newh.adress);
    printf("Number f rooms:       "); scanf("%d", &newh.nr_rooms);
    printf("Floors:      "); scanf("%d", &newh.floors);
    printf("Stars: "); scanf("%f", &newh.stars);
    printf("Enter position for insertion:  ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    p=inserth(h, n, k, newh); if (p==NULL)
    {puts("memory was not reallocated");}
    else {h=p;}
    getch( ); break;
```

('newh was not decl. in this  scope')Newh is a struct variable with fields name, adress,...why i got error when i tried to input info?Thanks!

Comment: There's no error in the C language.

Comment: where do you think `newh` is declared? [Post an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh by the way, doing `fflush` in an input stream (like `stdin`) is techincally *undefined behavior*. Some libraries allow it as an extension through, but don't count on it for portable programs.

Comment: Always a good idea for someone with rep of 1 to add "Error in language" to title of question.

Comment: Is that the full main?  I don't think so.  If it is, you never defined newh.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, `HOTEL newh` is mentioned as parameter of functions `appendh` and `inserth`, so these two variables are local for bodies of thes two functions (`appendh` and `inserth`, not in `main`). That means, function `main` cannot reach scopes of `HOTEL newh`. You need declaration of onother `HOTEL newh` inside `main()` before you use it and send to other functions as parameter.